# React Native Maps text above marker

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I wonder if its possible to deplay text on top of a marker so you know what the marker is without having to click on it

```
<MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      >
        <MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{ latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324 }}
        >
          <View>
            <Text
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                color: "black",
                textAlign: "center",
              }}
            >
              text
            </Text>
          </View>
        </MapView.Marker>
      </MapView>
```

Currently doing this but the marker disapears once i put the Text tag, if i remove it the marker shows up again

Comment: test to add style for your 'View'  and then change your Text style for example remove absolute position